# OS X Maintenance - how to keep the system clean?

Tags: macos, maintenance

I'm a .NET developer and a long time Windows user. Recently I've been working a little bit on OS X Leopard, trying to learn iPhone development.

So far so good - Mac OS X seems like a great operating system.

I'm assuming that temporary files and logs are being written somewhere, and programs leave junk behind. So I was wondering, how do you keep your Mac clean (please, no "Macs don't need fixin'" answers)?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually never do any maintenance directly since there are quite a few scripts that run weekly and monthly for this purpose.

However I do run [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/pgs/english.html) every once in a while to just make sure everything still works fine.

Comment: +1 - Also, repairing permissions seems to help. Yes it's no panacea, but it helps.

Comment: You will rarely (if never) have to "repair" permissions. That's only a task that should be done when there's a real permissions problem. Google a little bit, it can cause more harm than good.
Onyx (and Cocktail if you feel like paying) are great. I have Cocktail and 'tis nice.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is that deleted applications may leave behind support files in ~/Library and /Library. You can have these automatically deleted when you delete an Application using [AppTrap](http://konstochvanligasaker.se/apptrap/) (unfortunately it is no longer being developed. [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) does a similar thing, but that is shareware). Aside from that, there is nothing else that intrinsically needs cleaning. Logs and temp files are automatically cleaned.